# C++ Override >> operator

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

I am writing a program where an arbitrarily large number is represented by a doubly linked list where a node in this list represents one digit of the large number.

As part of the problem, I need to override the '>>' operator so that when I type in a large number, the program takes the number and creates a big_number class using that number. (big_number class is the doubly linked list representing a large number.)

My Override:

```
istream& >> operator(istream& in, big_number& n)
{
    //Code I need to write
    return in;
}
```

Comment: So what are you having trouble with?

Comment: You neither explicitly mentioned what problem you're facing nor detailed your class description.

Comment: Just how I'm supposed to override it. I have already overridden the << operator, so that it looks like: ostream& operator <<(ostream& out, const big_number& n)
{
 if(n.positive == false)
  out<<'-';
  
 node* cursor = n.head_ptr;
 while(cursor != nullptr)
 {
  out<< cursor->data;
  cursor = cursor->next;
 
 }
 return out;
}

Comment: big_number has a few private variables, a next and prev pointer, int digits, int base, bool positive. It has a bunch of functions that override a bunch of operators that allow you to add two big_numbers together, subtract them, multiply, test comparisons like ==, !=, <=, >=, etc.

Comment: You kind of forgot to ask a question. You need to ask a specific question explaining the specific problem you're having trying to accomplish your objective. No matter how you dress it up, "do my work for me" is not a question.

Comment: We're not psychic. How are we supposed to know how to use your `big_number` class?

Comment: I wouldn't use a linked list to represent an arbitrarily big number. A `std::vector` (or similar data structure if you have to code it yourself) would be more efficient.

Answer (score 2):

This line:

```
istream& >> operator(istream& in, big_number& n)
```

should be either

```
istream& operator>>( istream& in, big_number& n )
```

or

```
auto operator>>( istream& in, big_number& n )
    -> istream&
```

In your later SO postings, please include also your build command and error messages.

---

In passing, regarding terminology, this is an *overload*, not an *override*. The latter is what you have when you override a base class’ virtual member function.